# Automating "good" pagebreak (manual local pagebreak optimization)

Tags: page-breaking

I was recently typesetting a book with LaTeX where the publisher had the following requirements:

1. Absolutely no clubs; widows tolerated, but avoid if possible. (The text contained many 2-line and 3-line paragraphs.)
2. No hyphen at pagebreak.
3. Good looking pages.
4. I could choose the page layout to some extent (tuning margins and such).

The steps I did were the following:

1. With fixed `\textwidth`, use `microtype` for considerable paragraph flexibility. Find all `Overfull hbox` and adjust hyphenation of the word being broken, or adjust wording of the phrase; this was always in the first paragraph line.
2. Set `\clubpenalty=10000` and `\widowpenalty=10000`. Many `Underfull vbox` were the result. Find the best `\textheight` around given page size; I tried initial guess ±4mm with 1mm step. One of them generated the least number of Underfull vboxes, which was the pagesize I chose.
3. For each `Underfull vbox` page, find a paragraph which was close to being shorter (last line short) or longer (last line long) by 1 line. Set `\looseness` to `1` or `-1` and retry. Usually a better pagebreak was found right away by adjusting just one paragraph in this way, and only on the page where the problem was. Continue until no more `Underfull vbox` appear (with `\vbadness=3000`).
4. Visually find all hyphenations at page break, and put the word broken into `\hbox{...}` to prevent the break. In all cases, the paragraph was fine that way. (Using `\brokenpenalty` would move pagebreak but not try to not hyphenate.)

Some of the steps (#3,  #4) were highly repetitive. Although the approach is naive trial-and-error, only providing simple feedback from pagebreak to linebreak improved the result quite a bit in terms of something like local optimization.

The question is: is there some automation of these tasks already done or in the process of being programmed?  (I am not asking about Frank's [Alice goes floating](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2016-07-TUG%202016-Mittelbach-slides-with-notes-smaller.pdf) which has much broader goal of global optimization.)

Comment: Setting `\brokenpenalty = 10000` will prohibit a page break after a line that ends with a hyphen.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti yes, but that was usually the best (or only) line to break page, so `\brokenpenalty=10000` would cause `Underfull vbox` instead of just avoiding the hyphen and doing the page break there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In classic tex, without using lua callbacks there is not a lot more that can be done but...

step 2 sounds wrong.

`\textheight` should always be `\topskip` + some multiple of `\baselineskip` otherwise on a page with just text there is no possibility of avoiding an underfull box.

If you can allow yourself an extra line without adjusting the page size you can use

```
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
```

usually best to do on both pages of a spread of course.

but basically it requires hand tuning as you say.

you didn't say what you have `\parskip` set to. If you have lots of small 2-3 line paragraphs you presumably have lots of inter-paragraph space so if you set club and widow penalties so the paragraphs don't break one option (in some designs) is to make `\parskip` quite flexible so that in practice you can always take a three line paragraph over to the next page without making the current page under-full. If you need to keep vertical glue controlled or even not stretchy at all to keep things on a grid layout then more hand tuning is needed.

Comment: For a book with no mathematics and no headers apart from the chapters, anything other than `\parskip=0pt` usually looks messy.  If the OP did have several "large" breaks on most pages, the question probably wouldn't arise anyway. Personally, I just use the manual `\looseness` method that the OP doesn't like. Don't forget that you can sometimes stretch or shrink the number of lines in a long paragraph, to fix a page-break problem on a later page in the document.